# Jquery button with class selector doesnt work in chrome/firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple buttons on a page, on click of each button I am showing Un-ordered list and changing the clicked button color to grey and rest of buttons in page to white color. Below code works in IE but doesn't work in chrome/Firefox/safari.

Basically I am using jquery selector for button element with class name that will basically paint all the buttons in white color and then painting the clicked button with grey color.

```
$('button.o365button').css('background-color', 'white  !important');
```

I think above statement doesnt seem to work in chrome/firefox/safari. Any idea why this doesnt work.

Below is completed code that works

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.o365button').on('click', function(event) {
    //hide all the sub menus on page loaded
    $('.childHeaders').hide();

    //Open the submenu that was clicked    
    $(this).next(".childHeaders").toggle();

    //Change all button colors to white
    $('button.o365button').css('background-color', 'white  !important');

    //Change the clicked button to grey
    this.style.setProperty('background-color', '#d8d8d8', 'important');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="menu">
      <div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">   
       <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Products" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color: white !important;" aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Products</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav" style="width: 720px;">
      <ul id="Sco5">
        <li id="5"><a style="font-weight: bold;">Scorecards/Dashboards</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">
  <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Support" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color: white !important;" aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Support</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav">
      <ul id="Use31">
        <li id="31"><a href="https://unicef-insight1.uservoice.com/" target="_blank">User Support Portal</a>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

IE

[image]

Firefox/Chrome

[image]

Comment: did you try clearing cache? Try ctrl+f5

Comment: As you can see from the formatter problems when I made a snippet for you, the HTML is invalid - you cannot have a div in a span

Comment: Why are you using two different ways of changing the CSS. Just toggleClass your white

Comment: Yes I cache was cleared but no change in result.

Comment: You also can't have a `<ul>` as a child of another `<ul>`

Comment: You can simply write `$('button.o365button').not(this).css({'background-color':'white '});`
`$(this)`.css({'background-color':'grey'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `!important`  and `important`you have,and your code will work fine in Firefox/chrome too:-

Working example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.o365button').on('click', function(event) {
    //hide all the sub menus on page loaded
    $('.childHeaders').hide();

    //Open the submenu that was clicked    
    $(this).next(".childHeaders").toggle();

    //Change all button colors to white
    $('button.o365button').css('background-color', '#ffffff');

    //Change the clicked button to grey
    $(this).css('background-color', '#d8d8d8');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="menu">
      <div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">   
       <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Products" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color: white !important;" aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Products</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav" style="width: 720px;">
      <ul id="Sco5">
        <li id="5"><a style="font-weight: bold;">Scorecards/Dashboards</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">
  <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Support" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color: white !important;" aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Support</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav">
      <ul id="Use31">
        <li id="31"><a href="https://unicef-insight1.uservoice.com/" target="_blank">User Support Portal</a>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two different ways of changing the CSS. Just change classes and remove the styles from the buttons - you do not even need the important

PS: You cannot wrap a div in a span

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.o365button').addClass("white").removeClass("grey")

  $('.o365button').on('click', function(event) {
    //hide all the sub menus on page loaded
    $('.childHeaders').hide();
    $('button.o365button').addClass("white").removeClass("grey");

    //Open the submenu that was clicked    
    $(this).next(".childHeaders").toggle();

    $(this).removeClass("white").addClass("grey");

  });
});
```

```css
.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.grey {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="menu">
      <div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">   
       <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Products" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true"  aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Products</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav" style="width: 720px;">
      <ul id="Sco5">
        <li id="5"><a style="font-weight: bold;">Scorecards/Dashboards</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">
  <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Support" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Support</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav">
      <ul id="Use31">
        <li id="31"><a href="https://unicef-insight1.uservoice.com/" target="_blank">User Support Portal</a>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.o365button').on('click', function(event) {
    //hide all the sub menus on page loaded
    $('.childHeaders').hide();

    //Open the submenu that was clicked    
    $(this).next(".childHeaders").toggle();

    //Change all button colors to white
    $('button.o365button').not(this).css({'background-color':'white'});

    //Change the clicked button to grey
    $(this).css({'background-color':'grey'});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="menu">
      <div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">   
       <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Products" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color: white !important;" aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Products</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav" style="width: 720px;">
      <ul id="Sco5">
        <li id="5"><a style="font-weight: bold;">Scorecards/Dashboards</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="o365cs-nav-topItem">
  <button class="o365button o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365cs-topnavText ms-bgc-tdr-h" id="Support" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color: white !important;" aria-label="Opens the Settings menu" type="button"><span class="wf wf-size-x18 wf-family-o365 menustyle" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Support</span></button>
  <div class="childHeaders" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="subnav">
      <ul id="Use31">
        <li id="31"><a href="https://unicef-insight1.uservoice.com/" target="_blank">User Support Portal</a>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```